# How to handle DLL libs with Cmake - error DLL not found

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two files in a project local lib/ directory.  The files are oysters.lib and oysters.dll.

My CMake looks like this:

```
add_executable(MyProject ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(MyProject ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/oysters.lib)
```

When I try to run the exe

[image]
(Ignore the dll in the image, I changed the name to make it simpler.  Assume its missing oysters.dll)

Comment: A similar question was asked today.

Comment: Put the dll in the same folder as the executable. You could script that with CMake using a post build step or possibly [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html) Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089284/copy-all-dlls-that-an-executable-links-to-to-the-executable-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089284/copy-all-dlls-that-an-executable-links-to-to-the-executable-directory)

Comment: @drescherjm - I have just contributed an answer to the question you linked that works well in CMake 3.21+ using the new `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:...>`. @BAR, that answer should address the issue you're having here.

Comment: @AlexReinking thanks. I am sure that will be helpful when I get to modernize some of my 12+ year old CMake scripts..

Comment: Depending on whether you use the debugger or you want to deploy your own project with the binaries, setting the path for the debugger could work (`set_target_properties(MyProject PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${ONIXS_DLL_DIR};$ENV{PATH}")`). For deploying the `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES` parameter for [`install(TARGETS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets) could be useful.

Comment: @fabian I want to do both, use the debugger and build for prod.  I'm a little confused on what I should do, can you post an answer?