# cannot get .dll file copied to executable folder with CMake

Tags: dll, cmake

via this answer:

[How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

I'm trying to copy SDL2.dll to where my .exe is being stored. However, this isn't working for me. Here is my CMakeLists.txt file with the add_custom_command that is, theoretically, responsible for copying the dll to the target exe directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(Another)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

add_executable(Test "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SourCe/MAin.cpp")

find_path(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR SDL.h HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/SDL2/Include/")
find_library(SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR SDL2 HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/SDL2/Lib/x86")
find_library(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY_DIR SDL2main HINTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/SDL2/Lib/x86")

add_custom_command(TARGET Test POST_BUILD
     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
         "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/SDL2/lib/x86/SDL2.dll"
         $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Test>)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Test ${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Test ${SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

This is the only CMakelists.txt file in my project so I haven't altered where my exe is being stored (which it seems by default to be in the build folder under 'debug'). I'm still new to cmake so I was wondering if someone could guide me in the direction of my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the issue. The command I was looking for was "copy_if_different" and not "copy_directory" within the add_custom_command() function.