# CMake - Include third party files

Tags: c, windows, cmake, clion

I'm pretty new to working with third party stuff and also new to working on Windows with C.

I'm currently trying to simply use and include this [third party library.](https://github.com/Zeex/subhook)
I've downloaded it and put all the files in `include/subhook/` next to my main file.

My `main.c` looks like the example on the github page, except it includes `include/subhook/subhook.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include/subhook/subhook.h"

subhook_t foo_hook;

void foo(int x) {
    printf("real foo just got called with %d\n", x);
}

void my_foo(int x) {
    subhook_remove(foo_hook);

    printf("foo(%d) called\n", x);
    foo(x);

    subhook_install(foo_hook);
}

int main() {
    foo_hook = subhook_new((void *)foo, (void *)my_foo, 0);

    subhook_install(foo_hook);
    foo(123);

    subhook_remove(foo_hook);
    subhook_free(foo_hook);
}
```

and this is my CMakeLists.txt file. I've also tried including all the other .c files but it won't work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(NexusHookSubhook)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(include/subhook)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c include/subhook/subhook.h include/subhook/subhook.c)
add_executable(NexusHookSubhook ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

When I try to compile I get a whole load of these errors (which is, I assume, from linking/including the library wrong). Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

```
C:\Users\Nakroma\.CLion2017.1\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\Nakroma\CLionProjects\NexusHookSubhook\cmake-build-debug --target NexusHookSubhook -- -j 4
[ 33%] Linking C executable NexusHookSubhook.exe
CMakeFiles/NexusHookSubhook.dir/main.c.o: In function `my_foo':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Nakroma/CLionProjects/NexusHookSubhook/main.c:12: undefined reference to `__imp_subhook_remove'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Nakroma/CLionProjects/NexusHookSubhook/main.c:12:(.text+0x3c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_subhook_remove'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Nakroma/CLionProjects/NexusHookSubhook/main.c:17: undefined reference to `__imp_subhook_install'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Nakroma/CLionProjects/NexusHookSubhook/main.c:17:(.text+0x69): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_subhook_install'
CMakeFiles/NexusHookSubhook.dir/main.c.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Nakroma/CLionProjects/NexusHookSubhook/main.c:21: undefined reference to `__imp_subhook_new'
....
```

Additional notes: I'm on Windows 10 with Cygwin 2.8.0 and CMake 3.7.2 (using the make and gcc package and GDB 7.11.1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Comment: Duplicate explanations: aside from specifying headers directory with `include_directories`, you need to link with the library file with `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Note: with `add_subdirectory(include/subhook)` it at least compiles now, but on running it gives the error `error while loading shared libraries: cygsubhook.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, altough it is in `cmake-build-debug/include/subhook/`. Moving it results in successfully compiling and running. Any idea how to automatically place it there?

Comment: Solved so far. I've used this to copy the .dll into the .exe directory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you totally miss the linking part in your CMakeFiles

```
target_link_libraries(
    NexusHookSubhook
    ${subhookLib}
    m
)
```

Where subhookLib is the library of subhook.

Comment: That's the problem though, doing that results in `cannot find -lsubhook`.  
What I mean is, there is no `.so` or `.dll`

Comment: Is there any dll in the package furnished ? If yes maybe you have to add -L<pathToDllDirectory> to tell you compiler where the dlls are.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following things:

Replace

```
#include "include/subhook/subhook.h"
```

with

```
#include "subhook.h"
```

as first part of the path is already included over here:

```
include_directories(include/subhook)
```

Only include the .c files as SOURCE_FILES:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c include/subhook/subhook.c)
```