# Why doesn't CMAKE always copy resources when asked?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with some asset (shader) files that are also frequently updated and need to be copied to a build destination folder **every** time my project is built.

Right now, the files are copied the first time, but then, when the project is rebuilt (from within Clion) the files are not continually copied.  For instance, if I delete them from the directory they are copied to, they do not show up again.

Here is my Cmake file:

```
# Name for this project
set(PROJECT_NAME "3d_model")

# Choose the library for the final build
set(PROJECT_BUILD_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BUILD_DIR}/$<CONFIG>)

# Set sources
set(PROJECTS_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/projects)
set(SOURCES
  src/main.cpp
  ${INCLUDE_DIR}/glad/src/glad.c)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})

# Copy resources
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BUILD_DIR}/)
```

You can see in the last line my attempt to get the projects assets to copy every time the project is built.

Is there a way to ensure this happens?

Comment: The file(COPY ... ) happens during generation not building.

Comment: @drescherjm is there a way to make it happen during building as well?

Comment: `Is there a way to ensure this happens?` You need a custom target. See the help for add_custom_target()

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake

Answer (score 0):

`add_custom_command` may be what you want

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${ProjectName} PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets ${PROJECT_BUILD_DIR}/
 )
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything different than my posted code.

Comment: You may want to add the `PRE_BUILD` option to that.

Comment: @Startec Try adding `PRE_BUILD`