# CLion, MinGW and SDL2: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, sdl-2, clion

I am trying to add SDL2 to my CLion project. I found this [guide](https://github.com/muvox/roguetutorial) and tried to follow it while including only SDL2. Everything compiles, but when I start my app I get "Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)".

In my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Test)
    
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
    
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lmingw32 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
set(SDL2_PATH "C:/CPP/libs/SDL2-2.0.10/x86_64-w64-mingw32")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "C:/CPP/libs/CMakeModules")
    
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
    
if (${SDL2_FOUND})
    message(VERBOSE, "sdl found!")
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR, "sdl not found")
endif ()
    
message(VERBOSE, ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(VERBOSE, ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
    
add_executable(Test src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <SDL.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using CLion 2019.3.2 with bundled CMake, latest MinGW build (x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0) and latest SDL2 (2.0.10).
CMake output also looks ok:

```
VERBOSE,sdl found!
VERBOSE,C:/CPP/libs/SDL2-2.0.10/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
VERBOSE,mingw32-mwindowsC:/CPP/libs/SDL2-2.0.10/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2main.aC:/CPP/libs/SDL2-2.0.10/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2.dll.a-lpthread
```

Comment: The error `0xC0000135` means that some `.dll` used by your application cannot be found. Check that directories for all libraries used by your application are listed in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: BTW, in CMake function's arguments are delimited by a **space**, not by the comma (`,`). Your last `message` should be like this: `message(VERBOSE  "${SDL2_LIBRARY}")`. (Double quotes make output of elements in the `SDL2_LIBRARY` variable to be delimited by semicolon `;`.) Also, `-lmingw32` has no sense in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable: `-l` is a **linker** flag, not a *compiler* one.

Comment: Of course I forgot to add sdl.dll... Also fixed those cmake calls you mentioned, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using visual studio toolchains in CLion:

You need to paste in folder `cmake-build-debug` or `cmake-build-release` the files `.dll`,  but no only `SDL2_image.dll`, all files from folder `lib/x86`

[SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip)

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that your DLLs aren't being found at runtime, and you want to copy your SDL DLLs to the same directory, then you can do the following (see also [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10671916/11107541)):

```
if(WIN32)
  add_custom_command(
    TARGET Test POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different
      "$<TARGET_FILE:SDL2::SDL2>"
      "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:yourgame>"
    VERBATIM
  )
endif()
```

See also:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/WIN32.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-copy_if_different
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#target-dependent-expressions

Also related to this solution: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/6399.