# add a file to Vs project using CMAke so it will be copied to output directory during build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am creating a visual studio project in C++ using CMake to show how to use a DLL (This is our SDK so the codes are samples for the dll)

What I have at the moment, is to document to users that they need to manually copy the DLL to the debug/release directory of sample application so they can be found by sample applications.

I am wondering how I can add a file to a Visual Studio project in a way that the file is copied to output directory during build process.

the directory structure is as follow

```
MySDK\
    CMakeLists.txt
    src\
        main.cpp
    sdkDLL\
        MYSDK.DLL
```

and I am building the project in a build directory, so after I build a project with CMake, I should have a new directory called build in the root directory as follow:
       MySDK\
          build\
            MyProject.sln

at this stage there no debug or release folder, so I can not copy the dlls to them using CMake, it should be done using VS as part of the build.

Comment: I do basically this: [https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-January/048484.html](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-January/048484.html)

Comment: I suspect the clean option is missing. The MSBuild project generator in CMake would need to generate a [`CopyTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019). There appears to be no CMake command which does that.

Comment: Have you seen the [configure_file()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command with the COPYONLY option?

Comment: @Pesho_T That function doesn't work as it copies files during project creation by CMake, but we need to do this during build process of VS.

Comment: Maybe a custom command with `PRE_BUILD` keyword does this. `add_custom_command(TARGET yourtarget PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different <YOURDLL> <TARGETDIR/DLL>)`

Comment: @vre This seems to work, Can I use a GLOB to copy all files? What about making it work for all targets instead of for only one target? You may put it as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: To copy the contents of a directory use `copy_directory` instead of `copy_if_different` in the command. (See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) Will add a full answer later.

Comment: Is something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10672739/3987854) what you are looking for?