# I cannot connect to my MySQL database in C with CLion

Tags: mysql, c, api, cmake, clion

It's in the title, I want to create a program in C which connects to my MySQL database which is hosted locally with MAMP, I use as IDE CLion and I'm on Windows. I also use the MySQL API that I installed in my MinGW directory

So to do this I use this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <MYSQL/mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("\nhello");
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (con == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\ntest");
    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "root",
                           "perfect-concierge", 3307, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\ntest2");
    if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\ntest3");
    mysql_close(con);
    exit(0);
}
```

"Tests" are there to see where there would be an error. And I use this CMakeFile.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Test-MySQL C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall")
add_library(libmysql SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        libmysql
        PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB "C:/MinGW/lib/libmysqlclient.a")
link_directories("C:/MinGW/lib")
add_executable(Test-MySQL main.c)
target_link_libraries(Test-MySQL libmysql)
```

(PS : It is not me who made this CMakeFile but the one who gave me this example of connection to a MySQL database)

But when I execute this code the program compiles well, it runs then I get this error :

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Without anything else. I tried to just change the main function and just keep `printf("\nhello");` and the program worked correctly, but just add `MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);` send me this error again

Thank you in advance for the time you will take to help me.

Comment: can you check the my.ini file if the port os really 3307 and not the standard 3306?

Comment: Perhaps, because you are importing a *static* library, you should use `STATIC`, not `SHARED`, in the `add_library()` command.

Comment: Yes the good port is 3307, I don't know when it was modified but it is the right one.

Comment: I tried to replace `SHARED` with `STATIC` but during compilation it gave me this error : `CMakeFiles\Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Test-MySQL.dir/all' failed`

Answer (score 1):

The error

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

means that some `.dll` **cannot be found** when the executable is run (at **runtime**).

On Windows you need either

1. Have directory with `.dll` (`C:/MinGW/lib` in your case) to be in your PATH variable.
2. Have `.dll` itself near the executable (at the same directory). See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake) for the way how to achieve that in CMake.

---

Note, that `link_directories` (and similar) affects only on search the library during the *linking* stage and doesn't help at *runtime*.

Comment: That's it, I needed to put the dlls in the same directory as the executable, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

MAMP is Macintosh, Apache, MySQL, Perl/Python/PHP. Which is the Apache as web server, MySQL as database server and Perl/Python/PHP as a module for the Web Server. Moreover, the important thing, MAMP is compatible in MacOS/Macintosh.

As your description, you are using Windows as the operating system, and C as your program language. So, for sure you can not use MAMP as your server.

Alternatively, You need to find any server that compatible for your Windows OS and your C as program language.

Hopefully it helps!

Comment: Sorry but the problem did not come from there, actually it does not seem logical seen like that, but the problem came from the fact that the executable could not find the dlls, but thank you anyway