# CMake configure_file and Debug/Release directory

Tags: cmake

My executable needs a text file to run (with configuration and similar stuff), it is a simple text file, not generated and it is together in the source directory. I tried using `configure_file` and it works fine if I use any generator *that is not* Visual Studio or XCode. As soon as I try to do it using any of those two generators (in Windows and macOS respectively) the file is not copied in the Debug/Release directory but in the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`, I understand this happens because `configure_file` runs at configure time and not at build time, so I guess I cannot use things like `${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG}` to manually copy the file to that directory.

This is my CMakeLists.txt file, the `hello.cpp` is a simple hello world application and the file `sample.txt` is a simple file with a line of text:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(hello)

configure_file(sample.txt sample.txt COPYONLY)
add_executable(hello hello.cc)
```

Is there any way to add that `sample.txt` file as a direct dependency or something so it is copied at build time to the same directory where the output binary target?

Thanks a lot, I had been looking around the whole CMake documentation and questions without finding something relevant to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake) You can use `add_custom_command` to copy the text file as a `POST_BUILD` command to the directory containing the built executable (as shown in the first answer). Be sure to use CMake generator expression `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:hello>` so the correct Debug or Release directory is referenced.

Comment: Thanks @squareskittles that helped a lot! may you post this as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Happy to help! Your question was similar enough to the linked question, that *already* had several accepted solutions. So, your question has been marked as a duplicate, and I cannot provide an answer.