# Including SDL in program makes it have no output and instantly quit

Tags: c++, c, cmake, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a program with SDL2.0 but the program doesn't show any output and it quit instantly.
I am using Windows 10 x64 and I am doing this on VSCode, latest CMake version.
I actually tried `amd64`, `amd64_x86`, `x86`, `x86_amd64` toolchains, same thing happens.
A normal hello world program worked well but when importing SDL.h it wouldn't do anything, no output and delays.
C++ Program (main.py):

```cpp
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    printf("Hi\n");
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Delay(5 * 1000);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

When debugging the log stated that "MuserSDL.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135)".
CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(MuserSDL VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

include_directories(sdl/include)
link_directories(sdl/lib/x64)
message(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_executable(MuserSDL src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MuserSDL SDL2 SDL2main)

target_include_directories(MuserSDL PUBLIC sdl/include)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

The tree printed by `tree /a /f` (Reduced)

```
C:.
|   .gitignore
|   CMakeLists.txt
|   LICENSE
|   README.md
|
+---.vscode
|       settings.json
|
+---build (...)
|
+---sdl
|   |   BUGS.txt
|   |   ...
|   |
|   +---docs (...)
|   |
|   +---include
|   |       begin_code.h
|   |       close_code.h
|   |       SDL.h
|   |       ...
|   |
|   \---lib
|       +---x64
|       |       SDL2.dll
|       |       SDL2.lib
|       |       SDL2main.lib
|       |       SDL2test.lib
|       |
|       \---x86 (...)
|
\---src
        main.cpp
```

Comment: Your program works, it just miss the .dll next to it ;) That's why it crash at the very beginning.

Comment: @ErwanDaniel what should I do to let it find the .dll?

Comment: @Qiufeng54321 Just to copy them by hand is enough. But the solution using CMake is 100% good !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10672739/11225486). I should copy the sdl libraries under the target executable directory.