# CMake: How can I copy linked target DLLs if they exists?

Tags: cmake

Preliminary information: I'm stuck on CMake 3.19!

I have a project with many subprojects that build DLLs and excutables. I want all DLL and EXE files to end up in the build directory. I could already realize this by:

```cmake
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

DLLs from external libraries should also be copied. I have four ways I include 3rdparty libraries:

1. Header Only libraries via:

   ```cmake
   add_library(Eigen3 INTERFACE)
   target_include_directories(Eigen3 INTERFACE "/path/to/include")
   add_library(Eigen3::Eigen3 ALIAS Eigen3)
   ```
2. Binary DLL/LIB Files plus headers:

   ```cmake
   add_library(FreeImage SHARED IMPORTED)
   target_include_directories(FreeImage INTERFACE "/path/to/include")
   set_property(TARGET FreeImage PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/path/to/FreeImage.dll")
   set_property(TARGET FreeImage PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "/path/to/FreeImage.lib")
   add_library(FreeImage::FreeImage ALIAS FreeImage)
   ```
3. Standard `find_package` with targets as result:

   ```cmake
   find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
   ```
4. Direct specification of the DLL name in `target_link_library`.

I link my project via `target_link_library` to the targets of the libraries:

```cmake
add_executable(my_binary main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_binary
    Eigen3::Eigen3
    FreeImage::FreeImage
    Qt5::Core
    version) # version.dll from windows/system32
```

I want all DLL files of the direct dependencies of `my_binary` to be copied to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` after the build.

---

What I tried:

```cmake
function(update_dependencies PROJECT_NAME)
    get_target_property(LINK_LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_LIBRARIES)
    foreach(LINK_LIBRARY IN ITEMS ${LINK_LIBRARIES})
        if(NOT TARGET ${LINK_LIBRARY})
            continue()
        endif()

        get_target_property(TARGET_FILE ${LINK_LIBRARY} IMPORTED_LOCATION)
        if(NOT TARGET_FILE)
            continue()
        endif()

        message(STATUS "TARGET_FILE: ${TARGET_FILE}")
    endforeach()
endfunction()

update_dependencies(my_binary)
```

Output:

```
TARGET_FILE: /path/to/FreeImage.dll
```

This approach works only for `IMPORTED` libraries. The Qt core DLL included via `find_package` is not printed.

Because of [CMP0026](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0026.html), it seems I cannot simply query `LOCATION` instead of `IMPORTED_LOCATION`. When I enable the old behavior, it works the way I want in release mode. In the debug build it links against the Qt debug DLL, but it copies the Qt release DLL.

I also tried to work with `add_custom_command` and `$<TARGET_FILE:${LINK_LIBRARY}>`. The problem is that I seem to be able to query `TARGET_FILE` only if there is also a `TARGET_FILE`. Also, of course, I only want to execute the command if a `TARGET_FILE` exists.

Comment: Have you checked [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736197/3440745), which suggests to use `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS>` generator expression?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Forgot to mention, I'm stuck on CMake 3.19.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Nevertheless, that seems to be the right solution. I now have a workaround that works with 3.19 and relies on the old policy. As soon as we update CMake we can switch to this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CMake is at lease 3.21, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736197/3440745). (Thanks to commentator [tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev).)

I was able to find a workaround for CMake 3.19 by enableling the old `CMP0026` behavior and using `$<TARGET_FILE:${LINK_LIBRARY}>` instead of `${TARGET_FILE}`.

```cmake
cmake_policy(SET CMP0026 OLD)
function(update_dependencies PROJECT_NAME)
    get_target_property(LINK_LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_LIBRARIES)
    foreach(LINK_LIBRARY IN ITEMS ${LINK_LIBRARIES})
        if(NOT TARGET ${LINK_LIBRARY})
            continue()
        endif()

        get_target_property(TARGET_FILE ${LINK_LIBRARY} LOCATION)
        if(NOT TARGET_FILE)
            continue()
        endif()

        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
            copy_if_different
                "$<TARGET_FILE:${LINK_LIBRARY}>"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>"
            VERBATIM)
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```