# Linking wxWidgets in CMake Project

Tags: c++, cmake

I am building a C++ CMake application and I can't get the wxWidgets library to link correctly to the executable.
When I build it in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows, the FFTW3 and SDL2 `.dll` files are in the same directory as the executable, however, wxWidgets `.dll` files are not. Therefore, after running the executable, an error message appears that wxWidgets `.dll` files are missing. They are in their separate `/libs/wxWidgets/libs/.../*.dll` directory, but they are not linked to the executable.

I added the libraries as git submodules in my project and I am building them from source. Therefore, I am adding them using `add_subdirectory` and `include_directories`.

I am relatively new to this and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated!

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

if (UNIX)
    enable_language(OBJCXX)
endif (UNIX)

project(my_app LANGUAGES CXX C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_subdirectory(libs/SDL)
include_directories(libs/SDL/include)

add_subdirectory(libs/fftw3)
include_directories(libs/fftw3/api)

add_subdirectory(libs/wxWidgets)
include_directories(libs/wxWidgets/include)

add_executable(my_app WIN32 main.cpp ...)

target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE SDL2 fftw3 wx::net wx::core wx::base)
```

Comment: You say that they're not linked to the binary but they are? `target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE ... wx::net wx::core wx::base)`? `wx::*` are wxWidgets libraries right? So they _are_ linked to your binary.

Comment: @MarcDirven yes, I am linking them in the `CMakeLists.txt` but when I build the application (in VisualStudio), the application does not open and instead an error dialog is shown saying that the wxWidgets `*.dll` files couldn't be found. So they are not linking properly. In order for the app to start, I need to manually find these libraries in some subfolders and move them to the root folder where the `.exe` file is located. That's the thing I need to solve

Comment: Then you will need to copy the `wx` `.dll`'s to the same location as your executable. You can find more information on about how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake

Comment: I was afraid I would have to do this, I was hoping there was a better solution. I am going to do it this way then, thank you!