# CMake build project in subdirectory and copy output file

Tags: c, cmake, directory, subdirectory, cmake-language

I am attempting a CMake project that depends on the `PortAudio` library. PortAudio is contained in a portaudio subdirectory. According to the PortAudio docs, one can build PortAudio via CMake (on Windows) with:

```
cmake {portaudio path} -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Now the question is, how can I build PortAudio from the containing project's `CMakeLists.txt` and copy the resulting `portaudio.lib` file to a target directory?

My attempt so far is a `CMakeLists.txt` that contains:

```
add_subdirectory(portaudio)
configure_file(portaudio/Release/portaudio.lib portaudio.lib COPYONLY)
```

in a directory that contains the subdirectory `portaudio` with the PortAudio project contained within.

However, this attempts (and fails) to copy the file whenever `cmake` is run, but instead it should only do so after actually building the subproject (i.e. running the `--build` command on the portaudio subproject) so that the file alreday actually exists. More specifically, if I try to run just `cmake .` in the containing directory, it errs:

```
CMake Error: File C:/src/libs/portaudio/Debug/portaudio.lib does not exist.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
```

Adding the `-G` option for the VS version results in the same error.

What changes to CMakeLists.txt and/or my commands would I need to be able to `cmake .` in the containing project directory so that it builds portaudio and copies the lib file?

Comment: How about a `add_custom_command()` using the second signature where you can specify a TARGET (=portaudio) and POST_BUILD. Then you specify this copy command something like `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different <file>... destination>` and then it should be run once the portaudio lib has been built. The target must be defined within the current directory though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

Comment: in 99% of all cases copying a `.lib` file in the build step is the wrong decision. The install step should be the one putting the `.lib` file in the location it should be deployed at; if you don't want to deploy it, just using the absolute path should work. As for integrating the third party lib in your project: usually FetchContent or add_subdirectory would be used; if the project provides cmake configuration files and proper install logic, building&installing the project before/during the configuration step of your project and using `find_package` may be a good option.