CMake set output dir for dll
I have CMakeList.txt in the external folder
add_subdirectory(spdlog EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_subdirectory(SDL EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

And it connects to the root CmakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

set(PROJECT_NAME "JuicyEngine")
add_subdirectory(external)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(INCLUDE_DIRS
    "$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Include"
)

set(LINKER_FLAGS
    "-user32"
    "-lvulkan-1"
    "-L$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Lib"
)

add_compile_definitions(D_DEBUG JE_EXPORT)


set(SRC_FILES src/test.cpp
src/core/log.cpp)

set(INCLUDE_FILES src/defines.h
                src/test.h
                src/core/log.h
)

source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES
  ${SRC_FILES} ${INCLUDE_FILES}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC_FILES} ${INCLUDE_FILES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS} ${HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE spdlog)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SDL3::SDL3)


set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIG>
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIG>
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIG>
)


how can I set the directory where the assembled SDL.dll should be placed?
The DLL is now placed in the engine\build\external\SDL\Debug folder after building

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736197/12447766

You could set variable RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY at the beginning of your CMakeLists.txt (before add_subdirectory(external)). This setting will affect all targets, including the SDL one.
