Unit tests are missing dlls
So everything works on Ubuntu, on windows, unfortunately not. I have a project with one library and one app.
My root CMakeLists.txt is :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(WingWorkshop
        VERSION 1.0.0
        LANGUAGES CXX)

# Only do these if this is the main project, and not if it is included through add_subdirectory
if (CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME STREQUAL PROJECT_NAME)
  # Optionally set things like CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD, CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE here
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
  IF (WIN32)
    # set stuff for windows
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
  ELSE ()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-copy -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-unused -pedantic -O3 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wno-error=float-conversion -fPIC ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
  ENDIF ()
  # Let's ensure -std=c++xx instead of -std=g++xx
  set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

  # Let's nicely support folders in IDEs
  set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

  # Find ccache in the system
  find_program(CCACHE_PROGRAM ccache)

  # If ccache is found, use it as the compiler launcher
  if(CCACHE_PROGRAM)
    message(STATUS "ccache found: ${CCACHE_PROGRAM}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER ${CCACHE_PROGRAM})  # For C++ compiler
  else()
    message(STATUS "ccache not found, proceeding without it.")
  endif()

  # Testing only available if this is the main app
  # Note this needs to be done in the main CMakeLists
  # since it calls enable_testing, which must be in the
  # main CMakeLists.
  include(CTest)
endif ()

add_compile_definitions(_USE_MATH_DEFINES)

# Include CPM for dependency management
include(cmake/CPM.cmake)

# Use CPM to fetch spdlog
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME spdlog
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY gabime/spdlog
        VERSION 1.14.1
        OPTIONS "SPDLOG_BUILD_SHARED OFF"  # Ensure static library
)
# Use CPM to fetch cxxopts
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME cxxopts
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY jarro2783/cxxopts
        VERSION 3.0.0
)
# Use CPM to fetch openxlsx
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME OpenXLSX
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY troldal/OpenXLSX
        GIT_TAG ededa1e8398305d0983648d3e9f120ff7e228d2b
        OPTIONS "OPENXLSX_BUILD_DOCS=OFF" "OPENXLSX_BUILD_TESTS=OFF"
)
# Use CPM to fetch json
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME nlohmann_json
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY nlohmann/json
        GIT_TAG v3.11.2 # You can change this to the latest version if needed
)

# Add Eigen using CPM
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME Eigen
        GITLAB_REPOSITORY libeigen/eigen
        GIT_TAG 3.4
        OPTIONS
        "EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF"           # Do not build documentation
        "EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF"     # Optional, disables pkg-config
        "BUILD_TESTING OFF"             # Disable building and running tests
)

# CSV parser.
# Add csv-parser using CPM
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME csv-parser
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY vincentlaucsb/csv-parser
        GIT_TAG 2.3.0  # Replace with the appropriate version you want
        OPTIONS "CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON"
)
# Add PMP library using CPM
# Set EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR if it is not already defined
if (NOT DEFINED EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)
  set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "${Eigen_SOURCE_DIR}/")
endif()
find_package(Eigen 3.4.0 REQUIRED)
# Check if PMP is already included with CPM
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME pmp
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY pmp-library/pmp-library
        GIT_TAG 3.0.0  # Specify the version you need, or leave it out for the latest
        OPTIONS
        "PMP_BUILD_TESTS OFF"      # Prevents building tests
        "PMP_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF"   # Prevents building examples
        "PMP_BUILD_DOCS OFF"       # Prevents building documentation
        "PMP_BUILD_VIS OFF"
)

# Pass version number to the code
add_definitions(-DWINGWORKSHOP_VERSION="${PROJECT_VERSION}")

# Subdirectories
add_subdirectory(apps)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)

my src/CMakeLists.txt is:
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "*.cpp")

# Create the library from the collected source files
add_library(wing_workshop_lib STATIC ${SOURCES})

add_library(wing_workshop::lib ALIAS wing_workshop_lib)

target_include_directories(wing_workshop_lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)
target_compile_features(wing_workshop_lib PUBLIC cxx_std_20)

target_link_libraries(wing_workshop_lib PUBLIC spdlog::spdlog cxxopts OpenXLSX::OpenXLSX nlohmann_json Eigen3::Eigen csv pmp)

set_target_properties(wing_workshop_lib PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
)

# IDEs should put the headers in a nice place
source_group(
        TREE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
        PREFIX "Header Files"
        FILES ${HEADER_LIST})

and my app/CMakeLists.txt is:
add_executable(WingWorkshop app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(WingWorkshop PRIVATE wing_workshop_lib spdlog::spdlog nlohmann_json)

set_target_properties(WingWorkshop PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 20)

target_compile_options(WingWorkshop PUBLIC "$<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,MSVC>:/permissive->")

set_target_properties(WingWorkshop PROPERTIES
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)

The problem
Building an executable for my app works like expected. No problems there. However, running my unit tests no longer works.
The following is my test/CMakeLists.txt:
# Testing library
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME Catch2
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY catchorg/Catch2
        VERSION 3.4.0
)

add_executable(unit_tests
        io/test_obj.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(unit_tests PRIVATE wing_workshop_lib Catch2::Catch2WithMain cxxopts OpenXLSX::OpenXLSX Eigen3::Eigen csv pmp)
set_target_properties(unit_tests PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 20)
target_compile_options(unit_tests PUBLIC "$<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,MSVC>:/permissive->")

# If you register a test, then ctest and make test will run it.
# You can also run examples and check the output, as well.
add_test(NAME test_obj COMMAND unit_tests [obj])

# Labels.
set_tests_properties(test_obj PROPERTIES LABELS WW)

The executable is build and I can locate it in build/tests directory, but when I try to run it I get an error message saying that a bunch of dll files are missing, e.g. spdlog.dll, pmp.dll, etc.
I don't know how this happens. The unit_tests executable should use the same wing_workshop_lib as my app. But my app works, the unit tests don't.
Would anybody understand this? How could I fix this?
EDIT: Fixes.
Following @Tsyvarev's suggestion, I tried putting it all in the same dir.
This, I modified my src/CMakeLists.txt and added :
set_target_properties(wing_workshop_lib PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)

I also modified app/CMakeLists.txt and tests/CMakeLists.txt, by adding
set_target_properties(target_name PROPERTIES
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)

with appropriate replacement for target_name.
List of files generated in build/bin is:
    unit_tests.exe
    unit_tests.ilk
    unit_tests.pdb
    WingWorkshop.exe
    WingWorkshop.ilk
    WingWorkshop.pdb
    wing_workshop_lib.lib

Which seems OK to me, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

I guess the spdlog.dll and pmp.dll artifacts are in some build directory that is not in your PATH, so when you try to run tests executables from different directory, dynamic linker doesn't see them. You can add some post build CMake job to copy the dlls to some common build/bin directory where you can keep execs + dlls.

Also try set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin), maybe will work if dlls are considered "runtime".

@pptaszni Unfortunately, that didn't work.

On Windows running an executable will find a .dll library only when a directory with the library is listed in PATH variable or when both the executable and the library are located in the same directory. Which variant do you want to implement in your case? It is up to you to make this decision.

@Tsyvarev I tried throwing all of it in the same directory. (See the edits to my OP). I tried putting it all in build/bin. From what I see, the wing_workshop_lib.dll is there. But all the rest, like pmp.dll are missing. For clarity, the pmp.dll is located in build/_deps/pmp_build. However copy pasting the pmp.dll solves the problem. Is there a way I could do that with CMake or something?

@Tsyvarev With your help, I was able to fix this. May not be the cleanest solution but it works. I added this to my tests/CMakeLists.txt: add_custom_command(TARGET unit_tests POST_BUILD         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different         "$<TARGET_FILE:Catch2::Catch2WithMain>"  # Catch2 DLL         "$<TARGET_FILE:Catch2>"  # Catch2 DLL         "$<TARGET_FILE:pmp>"                    # PMP DLL         "$<TARGET_FILE:spdlog>"         "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:unit_tests>" )
Feel free to post this an answer.

I guess you have taken your solution from that answer. You could also try to use $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS> generator expression, which automatically collects dlls from the executable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736197/3440745
